# How to get the current time on the real-time Apexcharts

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

[realTime Apexcharts](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/blob/main/samples/vue/line/realtime.html)

I am making a real-time chart with the source code in the link above.
However, in the above chart, the value of the x-axis is not initialized to the current time.

Please tell me how to initialize the x-axis value to the current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this fragment

```
getDayWiseTimeSeries(new Date('11 Feb 2017 GMT').getTime(), 10, {
  min: 10,
  max: 90
})
```

to this

```
let initNumber = 10
getDayWiseTimeSeries(new Date().getTime()-(initNumber - 1)*TICKINTERVAL, initNumber, {
  min: 10,
  max: 90
})
```

Sarting x-axis will be from 13 to 22 (today)

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me how to change the x-axis unit to seconds?

Comment: Change `TICKINTERVAL=86400000` (1000*60*60*24 = day) to `1000` and `XAXISRANGE=777600000` (9*86400000) to `XAXISRANGE=TICKINTERVAL*9`. Also you'll have to too add `format` for tooltip https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/#xformat and xaxis https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/#format (you can use `format` or `formatter`)